# Draw discord avatar image on canvas from URL (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, image, http, canvas, discord.js

I am trying to draw the avatar image from a discord user onto a node.js canvas. According to the docs, I should just be able to put the url as the src like this:

```js
var img = new Canvas.Image;
img.onload = () => context.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h);
img.onerror = err => console.log(err);
img.src = url;
```

This doesn't work at all. So according to other sources, I have to fetch the image with an http client myself. Using Axios I get:

```js
function requestImageFromURL(url, callback){
    Axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
        callback(response.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {})
    .finally(() => {});
}

function drawImageFromURL(url, x, y, width, height){
    requestImageFromURL(url, function(buffer){
        var img = new Canvas.Image;
        img.onload = () => context.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height);
        img.onerror = err => console.log(err);
        img.src = buffer;
    });
}
```

but this throws some really strange errors like `Error: EINVAL, Invalid argument '�PNG → '`. So I kinda get the data, but canvas processes them not quite right? Or is there more pre-processing necessary on the data I receive?

Answer (score 0):

Calling class constructors should end with (). But in that code there's no (), just `Canvas.Image`. Try the first code using () and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. In the meantime, I used a workaround with Canvas.loadImage(url). It works but the code looks really ugly.

Answer (score 0):

`Canvas.Image` is a constructor. Therefore you'll have to use () so that you can manipulate it.

Should look something like this

```js
function drawImageFromURL(url, x, y, width, height){
    requestImageFromURL(url, function(buffer){
        var img = new Canvas.Image()
        img.onload = () => context.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height);
        img.onerror = err => console.log(err);
        img.src = buffer;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First step: Create background image, where your avatar will be drawn.

That's a part of my code which is sending message, when member join server, so don't mind `member` parameter.

`photo.png` stands for my background image.

```js
const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'jpg' }));
        context.drawImage(avatar, 40, 13, 120, 120);
        const attachment = new MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'photo.png');
        channel.send(`Welcome, ${member}!`, attachment);
```

Answer (score 0):

first you get the discord user avatar with method displayAvatarURL()  then load the image into canvas by method loadImage()  then draw image into canvas by ctx.drawImage()
by using new js features:

```
const img = message.author.displayAvatarURL({ extension: 'png' });
const image = Canvas.loadImage(img);
ctx.drawImage(image, 9, 9, 200, 200);
```

this solution worked with me